# R dataframe with nested vector

Tags: r

#### Background

In R this works:

```
> df <- data.frame(a=numeric(), b=numeric())
> rbind(df, list(a=1, b=2))
  a b
1 1 2
```

But if I want the list to have a vector, rbind fails:

```
> df <- data.frame(a=numeric(), b=vector(mode="numeric"))
> rbind(df, list(a=1, b=c(2,3)))
Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  invalid list argument: all variables should have the same length
```

And if I try to specify the vector length, declaring the dataframe fails:

```
> df <- data.frame(a=numeric(), b=vector(mode="numeric", length=2))
Error in data.frame(a = numeric(), b = vector(mode = "numeric", length = 2)) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 2
```

Finally, if I eschew declaring the dataframe and try rbind two lists directly, it *looks* like everything is working, but the datatypes are all wrong, and none of the columns appear to exist.

```
> l1 <- list(a=1, b=c(2,3))
> l2 <- list(a=10, b=c(20,30))
> obj <- rbind(l1, l2)
> obj
   a  b        
l1 1  Numeric,2
l2 10 Numeric,2
> typeof(obj)
[1] "list"
> obj$a
NULL
> obj$b
NULL
> names(obj)
NULL
```

#### My setup

I have a embedded device that gathers data every 50ms and spits out a packet of data.  In my script, I'm parsing a waveform that represents the states of that process (process previous frame and transmit, gather new data, dead time where nothing happens) with a state machine.  For each packet I'm calculating the duration of the process period, the gathering data period which is subdivided into 8 or 16 acquisition cycles, where I calculate the time of each acquisition cycle, and the remaining dead time.

My list basically looks like `list(process=#, cycles=c(#,#,#,#), deadtime=#). Different packet types have different cycle lengths, so I pass that in as a parameter and I want the script to work on any packet time.

#### My question

Is there a way to declare a dataframe that does what I want, or am I using R in a fundamentally wrong way and I should break each cycle into it's own list element?  I was hoping to avoid the latter as it will make treating the cycles as a group more difficult.

I will note that I've just started learning R so I'm probably doing some odd things with it.

#### Expected output

If I were to process 4 packets worth of signal with 3 acq. cycles each, this would be my **ideal** output:

```
df <- data.frame(processTime=numeric(), cyles=???, deadtime=numeric())
df <- rbind(df, list(processTime=0.05, cycles=c(0.08, 0.10, 0.07), deadtime=0.38)
etc...

  processTime cycles           deadtime
1 0.05        0.08 0.10 0.07   0.38
2 0.06        0.07 0.11 0.09   0.36
3 0.07        0.28 0.11 0.00   0.00
4 0.06        0.08 0.08 0.09   0.41
```

Comment: `data.frame` columns need to have equal lengths. There are two ways around this. First, store things in a `list`, as each list element can be vector, matrix, data.frame, etc. (this is the alternative that you suggest in your question). Second, a column in a `data.frame` can itself by a list that can contain vectors (your `cycles` variable for instance). This is possible using list-columns in the `tibble` package (each row of the tibble would contain process #, cycle vector, and deadtime #).

Comment: I don't think I understand dataframes very well.  Given what I'm trying to do (run statistics on on avg and stddev process time, cycle time (both total and individually) and dead time, what is the idiomatic thing to do in R?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/9126/implement-state-machine-pattern-using-s4-class) you can find a general approach for using state machine pattern via S4 classes under R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take a different stab. Dealing with just your first 2 records.

```
processTime<-c(.05,.06)
cycles<-list(list(.08,.10,.07), list(.07,.09,.38))
deadtime<-c(.38,.36)
```

For cycles, we created a list element with a list that contains 3 elements in it.  So cycles[[1]][1] would refer to .08, and cycles[[1]][2] would refer second element of the first list and cycles[[2]][3] would refer to the 3rd item in the second list.

If we use cbind to bind these we get the following:

```
test<-as.data.frame(cbind(processTime,cycles,deadtime))
test

  processTime           cycles deadtime
1        0.05 0.08, 0.10, 0.07     0.38
2        0.06 0.07, 0.09, 0.38     0.36
```

test$cycles[[1]] will return first list

```
test$cycles[[1]]
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 0.08

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 0.1

[[1]][[3]]
[1] 0.07
```

Whereas the 3rd element of the second list can be called with:

```
test$cycles[[2]][3]
[[1]]
[1] 0.38
```

You can also unlist later for calculations:

```
unlist(test$cycles[[2]])
[1] 0.07 0.09 0.38
```

To do this iteratively as you requested.

```
test<-data.frame()
     processTime<-c(.05)
     cycles<-list(list(.08,.10,.07))
     deadtime<-c(.38)
     test<-as.data.frame(cbind(processTime,cycles,deadtime))
test

  processTime           cycles deadtime
1        0.05 0.08, 0.10, 0.07     0.38  


     processTime<-c(.06)
     cycles<-list(list(.07,.09,.38))
     deadtime<-c(.36)
test<- rbind(test,as.data.frame(cbind(processTime,cycles,deadtime)))
test 

  processTime           cycles deadtime
1        0.05 0.08, 0.10, 0.07     0.38
2        0.06 0.07, 0.09, 0.38     0.36
```

Comment: My mental organization for this was the list taking the the place of a struct and the dataframe taking the place of an array of structs.  I'm not sure that that is an accurate representation.  I don't think I fully understand dataframes.  Tentatively what you've done here looks like what I want, except that I feel it is transposed.  I feel like each row should have columns of (process, cycles, deadtime) and if I have 30 packets of data then I should have 30 rows

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example, with expected output?

Comment: I've updated my question with what I'd ideally like to do and get

Comment: @Zack. I took a different tack based on your expected output. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: So since I'm parsing these packets in sequence, I would actually have 3 vectors/lists (one for processTime, cycles, and deadtime).  As I parse each portion of the packet I would do something like `processTime <-rbind(processTime, 0.05); cycles <- rbind(cycles, list(0.08, 0.10, 0.07)); deadtime <- rbind(deadtime, 0.38)`, and only create the dataframe at the end?

Comment: @Zack. I'm going out for a bit. Please post what your incoming data look like.  You can use dput() to get something you can share we can read in without typing.

Comment: I don't have access to it here. In short, I have waveform data in csv format "time, A, B", where `A` and `B` are 0 or 1 at that time. The packet starts on a falling transition on `B` (process time starts). `A` will be 0 or 1. When `A` flips, the process time ends and the first acq begins. The first acq ends when `A` flips again etc. The packet ends on a falling transition on B (next packet starts). My state machine handles all of this. At the end of the sequence it gives the duration for each phase of the packet and then starts over. I need to store the durations as they are detected

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134333/discussion-between-akadrhouse-and-zack).